# How could I fill up the NAMES of the Pokemon in my Pokedex 

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series

I tried [battle subway](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Subway) and the [battle institute](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nimbasa_City#Battle_Institute), and none of the new encounters came to my Pokedex.

When I capture a Pokemon, the Pokemon goes to my Pokedex with a small Pokeball on his left side. When I fight some Pokemon, he goes to my Pokedex WITHOUT the small Pokeball.

Like when I fought [Shauntal](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shauntal) from Elite Four and [Froslass](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Froslass_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) came to my Pokedex. but in Gen V Froslass is ONLY available by trade.

In the Global trade you can only search for Pokemon that you saw at least once. I want get more Pokemons in my Pokedex, so I will be able to trade more (eg.: [Tornadus](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tornadus) is a Pokemon BLACK ONLY, I never saw him, and I can't look for him in Global trade)

Comment: What are you asking here? Do you want to know easy ways to find Pokemon for your Pokedex?

Comment: I put more information on the question, sorry if was unclear before.

Comment: It is a great idea in Black 2 or White 2 to see all Pokemon (excluding event-only ones) in Unova because it gives you access to a special area with heaps of shinies, rares, and interacts like the shiny Haxorus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've filled both the Gen IV National Pokedex and the Gen V Unova Pokedex, except for Meloetta. Here are some guidelines:

- If you battle every trainer, you will be able to see every Pokémon in the local Pokédex, even if you can't catch it. The only exception are the version-exclusive Tornadus or Thundurus, Landorus (who requires both Tornadus and Thundurus to be present), and the event-only legendaries: Victini, Keldeo, Meloetta and Genesect.
- In *Pokémon Black & White 2*, an NPC tells you a story about Tornadus, Thundurus and Landorus, which marks all three as seen in your Pokédex.
- *Pokémon Dream Radar* on 3DS lets you catch Tornadus, Thundurus and Landorus, and trade these to *Black & White 2*.
- I completed my Tornadus/Thundurus/Landorus set by trading with a trustworthy friend. You only need to borrow it to fill your Pokédex. If you missed the event Pokémon, trading with a friend way to get those too.
- Meloetta hasn't been released yet by event. If you missed the Victini, Keldeo and Genesect events, you'll need to borrow from a friend to fill your Pokédex.

If you also want to fill the National Pokédex:

- To fill the National Pokédex (all 649), you will have to trade with other games.
- Between *Diamond, Pearl, Platinum, HeartGold and SoulSilver* you can catch all 493 Pokémon except 13 legendaries: Arceus, Celebi, Darkrai, Deoxys, Jirachi, Manaphy, Mew, Phione, Regice, Regigigas, Regirock, Registeel, and Shaymin.
- You will have to trade borrow most of the legendaries from a trustworthy friend, as the events for these Pokémon have long passed. However, Manaphy breeds to produce Phione, and event Regigigas unlocks the other three Regis in *Platinum*.
- *HeartGold/SoulSilver* only gives you one of the Hoenn starters and one of Ho-Oh/Lugia. You'll have to trade for the others.
- *HeartGold/SoulSilver* only gives you one of either the Red and Blue Orbs to unlock Kyogre and Groudon. If you can borrow the other and catch both Pokémon, Professor Oak will give you the Jade Orb, and you can catch Rayquaza.
- *Pokémon Emerald* (GBA) is an excellent source of Kyogre, Groudon, Rayquaza, Regice, Regirock, Registeel and the Hoenn starters. The three Regis will also unlock Regigigas in *Diamond, Pearl or Platinum*.

Comment: You mean Kyogre and *Groudon*, right?

Comment: Right, Kyogre and Groudon. Corrected the entry.

Comment: This answer fits the question more than @ben's answer

Comment: There are several legendaries you can get in BW2 including all 4 Regis, Latios, Latias and Cresselia.

Comment: You can get a Manaphy egg by trading with Pokemon Ranger as well

Answer (score 2):

The Battle Subway/Battle Institute act like the [Battle Tower](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Tower) from Diamond/Pearl:

> Additionally, Pokémon not registered in the Pokédex will not be registered upon being seen in a Battle Tower.

Since you can see rare/legendary Pokemon very easily in the Battle Tower, pokemon you see here are NOT added to your pokedex in any way. This means you'll never be able to trade for these pokemon in Global trades, you'll have to see them yourself or see them in a local battle with a friend, which will add them to your pokedex.

Comment: Do online battles with friends add pokemon to your pokedex? I was never sure about that so I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: I never used the Global battle, I don't have good Pokemons yet. But  Anyone knows if there i can fill up. Thanks for complete the information about the Battle Tower/Subway/Battle institute.

Comment: I don't believe so; I think it's only considered a "fair" sighting of a pokemon if you see a pokemon in a preprogramed trainer fight, you see them in the wild or you fight/trade the pokemon with a friend.

Comment: If you can update your answer, to be more complete, it's should be good for me Ben. The other way to fill up your pokedex is doing the GTS Negotiation. There you can trade Pokemons that you have for the ones you have never saw. I filled up to 492 (at moment) my Pokedex (pokemon white).

Comment: In most games you *can* see all the Pokemon in the region's local Pokedex via the course of the game, by seeing them in the wild and battling every trainer in the game. Some legendaries like Tornadus are shown to you in a book by certain characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just encountering Pokemon will only add their name to the Pokedex - in Pokemon Black/White you have to catch the Pokemon in order for them to be added to the Pokedex in more than name only, which is why your battle encounters are not being added.

The Battle Subway Pokemon encounters won't be added to your Pokedex. The Battle Institute encounters also will not be seen.

If you have Wifi, sign up for the Pokemon Global Link service to gain access to the Dream World. By visiting the Dream World in Black/White, you will be able to befriend Pokemon you would otherwise have to transfer or trade to obtain.

It appears (from reading various forums) that you cannot just "see" Pokemon in the Global Battle, either, for them to add to your Pokedex - you have to "see" the Pokemon in the game itself (either from other trainers, trades, or in the wild) for them to add to the Pokedex.

Comment: @Ashley I am not looking for them to have the pokeball on the side,.I am trying to get them in the pokedex (like when I fought the Elit 4 and Frosglass got into my pokedex, and I do not have the pokemon). I am looking for it to make the Trade more easy. (I can ONLY look for pokemons that i saw once at least)

Comment: So you want to know how to find Pokemon to trade?

Comment: Waitwaitwait, *seeing* pokemon still adds the NAME to the pokedex correct? That doesn't seem to be what they're asking about

Comment: Yeah, I realize now that what I answered isn't quite what they asked. Editing to add more information

Comment: @BenBrocka It's what i am asking for. I want to fill up my pokedex (with the names), and YES seeing ADD the NAME. But it does not work with Pokemon battles from subway or battle institute, so, i am kind in a corner here. How can i solve this ? help ?

Answer (score -2):

Or you can cheat by using a action replay code. If you have an action replay that is. I'm not saying that you should do that. Cause it lists them complely filled in as if you had caught that Pokemon. Which sometimes takes away from the fun of getting a new Pokemon then checking the Pokedex entry for it. But you just want to be able to trade to get the Pokemon and don't mind using you Action Replay for it...well I won't judge you. But I'v done it for past games. But it took away from the fun. I hope this helps.